# Git edit undo. How do I edit undo many files with git?

Tags: git

I just made a bunch of mistakes in a bunch of my files.

Now I want to revert all those files back to the last committed change.

How to I do this with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2 ...
```

To undo **all** of the changes you've made to **every file** in your working tree:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```